# Upper bounds on the Stirling approximation of binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The [Stirling approximation for binomial coefficients](https://www.blackhc.net/blog/2021/binomial-stirling/) gives
$$
\log \binom{n+k}{k} \leq (n+k) \log (n+k) - n \log n - k \log k =: f(n, k) \text{.}
$$
I want to obtain a nice upper bound on the right-hand side $f(n, k)$ to make it easier to handle (to be more specific, I want to use the resulting upper bounds to evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt{f(n, 1/x)} \, dx$).

A naive approach would be the following.
Setting $g(x) = x \log x$ for $x > 0$, we can rewrite
$$
f(n, k) = g(n + k) - g(n) - g(k) \text{.}
$$
Noting that $g$ is a convex function, we can use the Jensen inequality to get
$$
g(n) + g(k) \geq 2 g\left( \frac{n + k}{2} \right) = 
2 \cdot \frac{n + k}{2} \log \left( \frac{n + k}{2} \right) = 
g(n + k) - (n + k) \log 2
\text{.}
$$
Therefore we have
$$
f(n, k) \leq (n + k) \log 2 \text{.}
$$
However, this is too crude: the resulting bound is
$$
\binom{n + k}{k} \leq 2^{n+k}
$$
So what we have just done is nothing more than
$$
\text{(# of ways to select $k$ items out of $n + k$)}
\leq 
\text{(# of ways to select some items out of $n + k$)}
\text{.}
$$
**Question**: Is there any sophisticated way of upper-bounding $f(n, k)$?